# Timeout with INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm having timeout issues with the following instead of delete trigger under SQL Server 2008 R2. It only appears to occur when many ( > 6 or so)  `CustomFieldOption`s are deleted in the same transaction.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[DeleteCustomFieldOptionInsteadOfTrigger] ON dbo.[CustomFieldOption] INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ucf  SET ucf.PendingCustomFieldOptionIdValue = NULL, ucf.PendingProposedStateId = NULL
                FROM UserCustomField ucf
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomFieldOptionId = ucf.PendingCustomFieldOptionIdValue
    WHERE ucf.CurrentCustomFieldOptionIdValue IS NOT NULL;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE ucf FROM UserCustomField ucf
                INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomFieldOptionId = ucf.PendingCustomFieldOptionIdValue
    WHERE ucf.CurrentCustomFieldOptionIdValue IS NULL;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE ucf FROM UserCustomField ucf
                INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomFieldOptionId = ucf.CurrentCustomFieldOptionIdValue;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DELETE cfo FROM CustomFieldOption cfo
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.CustomFieldOptionId = cfo.CustomFieldOptionId;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
```

I realize further context will likely be required (I will update the question as needed) - am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: run a profiler trace for 'deadlock' and 'deadlock graph'

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: could you be a little more specific please re: the tracing I'd need to do?

Comment: Do your tables have appropriate indexes for the Joins on `deleted` you are doing? What does the execution plan look like for these statements?

Comment: @Martin Smith: Can you provide some details about what you'd consider *appropriate* indexes in this case?

Comment: @Martin Smith: Thanks for the hint; adding indexes for the foreign keys in my UserCustomField table resolved this issue - if you'll add your comment as an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your tables have appropriate indexes for the Joins on deleted you are doing? What does the execution plan look like for these statements?

Answer (score 2):

I would first determine if you are experiencing a deadlock: [How to Track Down Deadlocks Using SQL Server 2005 Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/) (applies to SQL Server 2008 R2 as well)

[Incidentally: you only need one instance of `SET NOCOUNT ON;` per stored procedure]

Secondly, (as per @Martin's comment) what indexes do you have on these tables? The right (covering) indexes can make a huge difference both to overall performance and blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the information; looks like it may take quite a bit of legwork to get to the bottom of this issue.